# Django How to make only one query with queryset exists method?

Tags: python, django

I try to understand [Django documentation for queryset exists method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

> Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you
>   know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists()
>   will do more overall work (one query for the existence check plus an
>   extra one to later retrieve the results) than simply using
>   bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if
>   any were returned.

What I'm doing:

```python
    if queryset.exists():
        do_something()

        for element in queryset:
            do_something_else(element)
```

So I'm doing more overall work than just using bool(some_queryset)

**Does this code makes only one query?**

```
    if bool(queryset):
        do_something()

        for element in queryset:
            do_something_else(element)
```

If yes where python puts the results ? In queryset variable ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `.exists()` docs itself:

> Additionally, if a `some_queryset` has not yet been evaluated, but you
>   know that it will be at some point, then using
>   `some_queryset.exists()` will do more overall work (one query for the
>   existence check plus an extra one to later retrieve the results) than
>   simply using `bool(some_queryset)`, which retrieves the results and
>   then checks if any were returned.

The results of an already evaluated `queryset` are cached by Django. So, whenever the data is required from the queryset the cached results are used.

Related docs: [Caching and QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to check number of queries with assertNumQueries:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertNumQueries

In your case:

```
with self.assertNumQueries(1):
    if bool(queryset):
        do_something()

        for element in queryset:
            do_something_else(element)
```

Comment: Thank you It will helps me with my tests. Good link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries